# Unknown for loop inside of an remove method in a Double Linked List?

Tags: java, linked-list

I recently made a java code with a double linked list. However, it seems this remove method has a while for loop in it I cannot figure out.

If someone can help me verify this, it would be great. I already concluded that this specific method has the for loop in it.

```
public void remove(Node value){
    Node temp = head;
    while(temp != null){
        if(value.food.equals(temp.food)){
            addtofront(temp);
            if(temp.next == null){
                temp.back.next = null;
                temp.back = null;
            }
            else{
                temp.back.next = temp.next;
                temp.next.back = temp.back; 
        }
        }
        temp= temp.next;
        System.out.println("Print");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop only terminates if temp (the next object in the list) is null meaning it will iterate through the whole list of objects until the end, even if you have found the item to remove. This can be fixed by adding an extra condition such as a boolean removed to the while loop to ensure that it will terminate early if the object to remove has been found in the list.

```
boolean removed = false;
while(temp != null && !removed) {
//search list for item to remove
//when the item has been removed, set removed = true;
}
```

It is always a good idea to trace your loops through one case step by step to see exactly what is happening and where the problem is.